# SUMIF function in Google Sheets returns always 0

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to do a very simple SUMIF operation in Google Sheets but somehow the result is not what I expect. I believe I followed the syntax correctly and if I do the same in Excel, I get the result "2" that I'm after. Does anyone know the cause for this behavior? And hopefully the solution? Thanks!

[image]

Update: Removing the quotes, the result is the same. The cell with "2" is highlighted for reference of the content.

[image]

Comment: Remove the quotes around 2.

Comment: Same result as before!

Comment: I've updated the OP with a screenshot of the Q7 cell. What can I do to continue troubleshooting?

Comment: Share a link to a copy of the sheet?

Comment: I copied this section of my current worksheet to a new document: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qs6cLxaM9xzbW4tijIhhC1I6_LtdUBpEZE-UM5sLslg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry, fixed now!

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more the criteria you are using for the SUMIF?

Comment: I want to go over that range and sum the values that match my target. This is just a small example and it's clear there's something fishy behind, especially since this works in Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you may have a different format or something related to it that may be affecting the function as it may not be taking the values correctly.

I just copied the exact same values that you were using, then changed the format to "number" from the input and output cells and it started working without any problem.

I made a test by changing any other values from the column to be 2 and it works fine (see screenshot).

[image]

Second example:

[image]

This is how I changed it when going to `Format` > `Number` > `Custom number format`, and selected the first option.

[image]

Comment: You're right, that's a great catch! Apparently the format prevents the sum from being properly executed even though the condition is evaluated correctly. The sum range to needs to be numeric, even though the  range can be text. Thank you!